# FullCalendar eventRender problem = Unknown option 'eventRender'?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am unable to get eventRender to work.
anyway I add it, I get "Unknown option 'eventRender'.

What am I doing wrong?

Here a short code that already show the error:

```
<body>
<script>         
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {            
                    var date = new Date(); 
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    eventRender: function(info){
                        console.log("1");
                    },
                    events: [
                        {
                            title: "hello",
                            start: date,
                            allDay: true,
                        }
                    ],            
                  });
                  calendar.render();
                });
                
                </script>

    <div id = "calendar">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "eventRender" hasn't existed since version 3. If you're using version 5 then the equivalent options available to you are listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks . Please always check the documentation carefully and also if you are trying to use examples, check that they apply to your version of fullCalendar.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I will follow your advice :). Always learning...

Comment: Solutions on the internet can be outdated, so always check the FullCalendar upgrade guide for transfering to current version: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#event-rendering

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you are using new version, use eventDidMount like this:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {console.log(1);}
```

look this example from documentation: [event tootip example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo)